# Get Outlook 2010 Rule description

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing add-in for Outlook 2010. I have to get all rules and descriptions for them. I can access to the rules, but I don't understand how to get descriptions like on the picture. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule description isn't provided directly in the **VSTO API** - but you could interpret it yourself by enumerating and translating the [Rule Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867147.aspx) (*[`Rule.Conditions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869579)* / *[`Rule.Exceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867239)*), and [Rule Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868996.aspx) (*[`Rule.Actions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862765)*).

Comment: I've tried to do that, It seems to me that those Collections have not informative content. Maybe I have to find out how exactly to translate.